# How do you subtract from a negative integer but add to a positive?

Tags: c#, integer, increment, decrement

Simple question really, although I'm not sure if there's an answer.
I am handling an integer which can be positive or negative.

However, I would like to either increment or decrement it dependant on the sign.

*For example, if it's "2", then add 1 and make it "3".*

*If it's "-2", then subtract 1 and make it "-3".*

I already know the obvious method to fix this by adding if statements and having two separate increment and decrement sections. But, I'm trying to limit the amount of code I use and would like to know if there's a similar way of doing this from a  built-in function or procedure.

Comment: Please provide your code in here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it:

```
int IncOrDec(int arg)
{
    return arg >= 0 ? ++arg : --arg;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, will use this now!

Answer (score 6):

You can use built-in [Math.Sign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd3y5wdf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a + Math.Sign(a); // b == 2

int c = -1;
int d = c + Math.Sign(c); // d == -2
```

Or even shorter version, suggested in comments:

```
int a = 1;
a += Math.Sign(a); // a == 2

int c = -1;
c += Math.Sign(c); // c == -2
```

Comment: Note that this could be reduced to "a += Math.Sign(a);", which is both shorter than other solutions and still readable. This is therefore probably the best option.

Comment: @Chris, true, although actually it depends on whether you need to inc|dec the same variable.

Comment: Yep, but since the questioner actually explicitly said they need to incr/decr the variable, that seems a pretty safe bet here.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use ternary operator like this:-

```
num >= 0 ? ++num : --num;
```

Comment: Hey buddy, aim was to avoid using any if clause.

Comment: As the OP states this way (adding if statements) is already known and not the answer to this question.

Comment: Eeek ! if (positive==true)

Comment: Ha ha ha, typical coder`s perspective ;) +1 for corrected answer

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to clutter your code you can use [Ternary Operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a);

```
int number = (original > 0) ? original + 1 : original - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace posneg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = Int32.Parse(args[0]);

            Console.WriteLine(( num + ( num / Math.Abs(num) )));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just need to make sure to indent all code bocks (there's a little "code" button in the text editor to help with that)

Comment: As an explanation. Math.Abs() gives the positive value of any integer. Dividing an integer by itself will always give 1 (including if they are both negative). So dividing a negative integer by it's positive value will give -1, the same math will give +1 if the integer is positive.  No conditionals involved.

Comment: @ShivamMalhotra I know you've got a good answer there but I'm sure you'd be interested in this one :-)

Comment: It wasn't explicitly outlined in the question, but what if `num` is zero?

Comment: Then it goes boom!  :-)

(bother)